# Conditional isn't working while checking input type int

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well I'm very very new to python programming and still learning.So I tried to create a function where I used **len** to count the number of letters in a string.But since, **len**  doesn't work for integers I set up conditionals so that it would return a message saying "integers don't have length".
But I'm not getting the message even when I type an integer. please help me to solve this.
here is my code:

```
def Length_String(L):
    if type(L) == int:
        return "sorry,integers don't have length"
    else:
        return len(L)
x = input()
y = Length_String(x)
print(y)
```

It's not that important but still I want to know what is causing the conditional not to work. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you can always type `help(whatever)` in a Python prompt to read some useful stuff about it:

> `input(...)`
>
> ```
> input([prompt]) -> string
>
> Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
> If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
> On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
> is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
> ```

So you always get a string. One way to see if this string **could** be converted to an integer is:

```
try:
     int(L)
     return "Error, this is an integer!"
except ValueError:
    return len(L)
```

Of course, this won't work for floats, so there maybe more checks you want to do (or just use `float(L)`). Another way

```
if L.isnumeric(): # or isdigit or isdecimal
    return "Error, this is a number!"
return L
```

Here it's worth mention that in addition to the help which can show methods you can always type `dir(something)` in a Python prompt so see some useful methods in a list.

Answer (score 2):

They [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function in Python returns a value of type `str` even if what you type in is an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `input()` returns string no matter what you enter. So you don't need to check if the entered value is an `int`. If you still want to check it, you could do it with `isinstance` function:

```
if isinstance(L, int):
    return "sorry,integers don't have length"
```

Comment: Note that this would still say the length of `L` in your case because you don't convert it to an `int`